# Showing Green Guide Layer in Adobe Illustrator 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, grids, guides, smart-guides

I have some artboards to finish before the end of March. I want to display the Green Guide Layer as shown in the image. Can anyone help me to display it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Do *View > Rulers > Video rulers*
2. Then in the bar along the top click on Document Setup, then Edit Artboards
3. Click on the Artboard Options button in the bar along the top

[image]

4. Enable the following options: Show Centre Mask, Show Cross Hairs and Show Video Safe Areas.

Note: the screenshot above is from Illustrator CC 2018. So there may be some differences.